# How to select rows from 2 timestamps at determined hour?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I'm trying to figured it out how to get data with 2 timestamps... In context what I need is

I need to get all the rows that were inserted after yesterday at 4pm until 4pm of today...

I was thinking something like this ...

```
and (transaction_date between to_char(current_timestamp-1, 'DD/MM/YY 16:00:00') and to_char(current_timestamp, 'DD/MM/YY 16:00:00'))
```

but it tells me

> ORA-01821: formato de fecha no reconocido
>   01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

my transaction_date field is a timestamp field

any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Is `transaction_date` a `date`?  Or a `timestamp`?  Those are two different data types.  It doesn't appear to make any sense to mix the two here.

Comment: Hello @JustinCave yes, transaction_date is a timestamp

Comment: Just a plain `timestamp`?  Not a `timestamp with time zone` or a `timestamp with local time zone`?  Is there a reason that you chose a column name that strongly implies that the data is a `date` when it's really a `timestamp`?

Comment: Yes it has localtimezone, ( TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE ) and a example of one row is "21/01/14 06:49:57,900573000" hmm yes I chose this because for me it was the date the row was inserted including the time, and I didn't wanted to named it like "transition_timestamp" :)...

Comment: nevertheless @JustinCave you saved my life again it works and it is what i need thank you very much I owe you a beer, see ya ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `transaction_date` is a `date`

```
transaction_date BETWEEN trunc(sysdate-1) + interval '16' hour -- Yesterday at 4pm
                     AND trunc(sysdate) + interval '16' hour   -- Today at 4pm
```